# Loading orc files from a client node into Vertica

Tags: vertica, orc

Are there any ways to load orc files which reside on a client machine into Vertica table?

What I tried was [COPY LOCAL](https://www.vertica.com/docs/9.2.x/HTML/Content/Authoring/AdministratorsGuide/BulkLoadCOPY/UsingCOPYAndCOPYLocal.htm) but it's stated in the doc that by some reason:

> ORC and Parquet Hadoop files not supported with COPY LOCAL

Answer (score 1):

As you mentioned, Vertica doesn't support COPY LOCAL for ORC/Parquet files. You can either copy the files to Vertica server or to a shared directory, such as HDFS or AWS S3, and then use COPY FROM directly. For example:

```
-- copy from Vertica server:
copy t1 from '/path/to/orc/files/*' orc;

-- copy from HDFS:
copy t1 from 'hdfs:///path/to/orc/files/*' orc;

-- copy from AWS S3:
copy t1 from 's3://s3_bucket/path/to/orc/files/*' orc;
```

Comment: Or an NFS mount point, which might be easier (if you aren't already running Hadoop or paying for S3).